# how to test the same function from various modules using pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to run my test for a function from different modules (in one module I define the function that calls some C++ code and in the other module I have the same function that calls different code). What is the way to do it using py.test?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation and custom fixtures. sections parametrizing-tests and the-metafunc-object

Comment: Thanks for suggestion I decided to use `pytest_generate_tests(metafunc)` and it works.

Comment: Make it an answer and post your code for the community & a link to the material. Thanks!

Comment: ok, I've done it, but changed the original question, so it better matches the solution I finally use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use metafunc and create `conftest.py` file with `pytest_addoption` and `pytest_generate_tests` functions:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--libname", action="append", default=[],
                     help="name of the tested library")

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'libname' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize("libname", metafunc.config.option.libname)
```

And in the function in your `tests.py` file you can use importlib and ask for libname:

```
def test_import(libname):
    import importlib
    tested_library = importlib.import_module(libname)
    .......
```

Now, running your test you should provide the name of the module you want to test:
`py.test tests.py --libname=your_name1` (you can also add `--libname=your_name2`)